What tribe was Shmuel from?
I’ve seen conflicting answers, one that he was from shevet Efraim and one that he was from shevet Levi.
Does anyone have a real source for which it was?

The Ephraim idea is because Elkana or one of his ancestors is called an Ephratite in Shmuel 1:1:1. The Levite is from Shmuel's genealogy in Chronicles. There are various explanations for why Elkana or his ancestor were titled Ephratite. But there are also people who think that Chronicles invented Shmuel's Levitite origins.

There is a Midrash (Yalkut Shimoni 42:5) which discusses all the kings and judges that came from the various tribes.
In that piece it writes:

עלי ושמואל משבט לוי
Eli and Shmuel came from the tribe of Levi.

This standpoint is also taken by Shelah Hakadosh here:

והנה דוד מלך ארבעים שנה (ש"ב ה, ד), וכל זה מרומז בשם שמואל שהוא אותיות שאול מ', ושאול רומז על המלך, ומ' רומז על ארבעים שנה שמלך דוד. ושמואל היה משבט לוי אשר לו כתר כהונה. ושמואל שקול כמשה ואהרן (תו"כ שמיני ז), כי היה לוי נקרא על שבט לוי, אבל היה ג"כ צד כהונה כי היה הגלגול של אהרן הכהן, אשר על כן כתיב (שמות ד, יד) הלא אהרן אחיך הלוי, כי שמואל הלוי הוא אהרן הכהן, ורז זה גילה האר"י ז"ל והבאתי דבריו לעיל
David ruled for forty years. This figure is alluded to in the name Samuel which is comprised of the letters in the name Saul, שאול, with the letter 40=מ added. The first four letters allude to Royalty, the last to the 40 years David reigned. Samuel was from the tribe of Levi which wore the "crown" of Torah. Samuel himself was considered as equal to Moses and Aaron combined. Although he was known as a Levite, being a member of that tribe, he combined within himself elements of the priesthood, being traditionally considered the re-incarnation of the High Priest Aaron. When G–d told Moses in Exodus 4, 14: הלא אהרון אחיך הלוי וכו', "Is there not your brother Aaron the Levite?" He implied that there would be a Levite who at the same time was Moses' brother Aaron, i.e. Aaron's re-incarnate, the prophet Samuel. This secret has been revealed by the Arizal, and I have quoted his words on a previous occasion.

As far as the Efraim claim, this can be debunked. The Midrash in Vayikrah Rabbah 2:3 explains that Yaakov blessed Efraim that leaders would descend from him:

אָמַר רַבִּי פִּנְחָס עֲטָרָה זוֹ נִתְעַטֵּר אֶפְרַיִם מֵאָבִינוּ יַעֲקֹב בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁנִּפְטַר לְעוֹלָמוֹ אָמַר לוֹ אֶפְרַיִם רֹאשׁ הַשְּׁבָטִים רֹאשׁ הַיְשִׁיבָה יָפֶה וּמְעֻלֶּה שֶׁבְּבָנַי יְהֵא נִקְרָא עַל שְׁמֶךָ (שמואל א א, א):
Rabbi Pincḥas said: Efraim was granted this crown by Yaakov our patriarch when he passed to his eternal abode. He said to him: ‘Efraim, tribal leaders, yeshiva heads, and the finest and most outstanding of my descendants will be called by your name.’

The Yefei To'ar writes there:

ראש השבטים כו'. פי' כל מי שיהיה ראש וחשוב יקרא על שם אפרים. ומביא ראיה על ראש ישיבה משמואל דנקרא אפרתי אף כי היה משבט לוי.
Tribal leaders - This can be explained to mean that anyone who is a leader and important will be called by Efraim's name. And a proof can be brought about Rosh Yeshiva from Shmuel who was called "Efrati" even though he was from the tribe of Levi.


"Samuel himself was considered as equal to Moses and Aaron combined."  So Samuel, not Moses, was "the greatest prophet in Israel"?

No necessarily. He could have been considered "better" in middos etc. whereas Moshe was unmatched as far as nevuah? Feel free to ask the question @Maurice

Another nameless downvote...what was so offensive this time?

@Dov it could also just be in terms of leaderships qualities. Moshe never deviated even slightly from the word of Hashem, and for that reason Bnei Yisroel always gravitated towards Ahron who was more understanding. It may just be that Shmuel was a perfect balance of the 2, kind of like Yehoshua.

Why are you citing various later midrashim for something that's an explicit pasuk?

@DoubleAA only because it says it clearly and I knew the sources to hand...

Shmuel was from shevet Levi. Rashi explains that this is explicit in Divrei Hayomim:

אלקנה. לוי היה, מבני אביאסף בן קרח, כן נתייחס בדברי הימים (א ה ח):
Elkonoh. He was a Levite of the sons of Aviosof, the son of Korach —his ancestry is thus recorded in Divrei Hayomim.
https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_I_Samuel.1.1.3


This is correct but do you really need to cite rashi?

I need someone to tell me that the Elkonoh there is the same one as here.

Shemuel is mentioned there in divrei hayamim with the same kids as in sefer shmuel. I'm guessing you didn't check since you left the mistaken citation in the quote (it's chapter 6)

Actually I had checked and stopped reading too soon. There in chapter 6 pasuk 12 Elkonoh is mentioned, and then in pasuk 13 we have Shmuel, not necessarily in continuation, with a son Vashni, or maybe not, see Rashi there. Since that pair of pasukim is somewhat ambiguous I felt the need for Rashi. But I missed pasukim 18-23 which are unambiguous.
